# Send PIL Image from Django View to Browser for Download via HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, httprequest

I'm trying to send a PIL image from a Django view to the browser for automatic download. The code below seems to work for many:

```
 response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/jpg')
 PIL_imageToSend.save(response, "JPEG")
 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="name.jpg"'
 return response
```

I call the Django view through Ajax, and when I print the callback I get what looks to be the JPEG image, but no download is triggered. Am I missing something to get the download to automatically trigger?

Comment: is PIL_imageToSend a custom function? have you tried using this method? http://effbot.org/zone/django-pil.htm

Comment: PIL_imageToSend is the python variable containing the PIL image instance

Comment: In that article it looks like they're doing something pretty similar to what I have in the code snippet above. Not sure why the download isn't triggering... but thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 1):

The better/working approach is, first save your image to any location, then read it from there to prepare your response like this:

```
file = open('Read_From_Location/name.jpg', "rb").read()
rea_response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='image/jpeg')
rea_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format('name.jpg')
return rea_response
```